# How to upload downloaded telegram media directly on google drive?

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, telegram, telethon

I'm working on the telethon download_media method for downloading images and videos. It is working fine (as expected). Now, I want to directly upload the download_media to my google drive folder.

Sample code looks something like:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from telethon.tl.types import PeerUser, PeerChat, PeerChannel
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive

gauth = GoogleAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
gfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id': 'drive_directory_path'}]})
api_id = #####
api_hash = ##########

c = client.get_entity(PeerChannel(1234567)) # some random channel id

for m in client.iter_messages(c):
        if m.photo:
            # below is the one way and it works
            # m.download_media("Media/")
            
            # I want to try something like this - below code
            gfile.SetContentFile(m.media)
            gfile.Upload()
```

This code is not working. How Can I define the google drive object for download_media?

Thanks in advance. Kindly assist!

Comment: Welcome to stack please define "This code is not working."  We need to know what is not working are there errors if so what is the error is the file not uploaded?   From what I can see you are missing quite a bit of the authorization functionality.   Which probably means you are getting a not authorized error.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo, Drive authentication is not an issue. The way I mention the ```gfile.SetContentFile(m.media)``` is not right we define the image path in this argument.  I am not sure what is the right way to write code for directly uploading media files of telegram messages over drive. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: That's not how it works. None of these libraries know how to talk to each other. What you can do, inspect the source code of how telethon saves the bytes and how pydrive uploads the file bytes then and send each file byte as you receive them. But you can't have them directly uploaded from telethon to google drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that according to PyDrive's documentation, [`setContentFile()`](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/pydrive.html#pydrive.files.GoogleDriveFile.SetContentFile) expects a `string` with the file's local path, and then it just uses [`open()`](https://github.com/googlearchive/PyDrive/blob/42022f9a1c48f435438fce74ad4032ec9f34cfd1/pydrive/files.py#L165), so you're meant to use this with local files. In your code you're trying to feed it the media file so it won't work.

To upload a `bytes` file with PyDrive you'll need to convert it to [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) and send it as the `content`. An example with a local file would look like this:

```
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

file = drive.CreateFile({'mimeType':'image/jpeg', 'title':'example.jpg'})
filebytes = open('example.jpg', 'rb').read()

file.content = io.BytesIO(filebytes)
file.Upload()
```

Normally you don't need to do it this way because `setContentFile()` does the opening and conversion for you, but this should give you the idea that if you get the `bytes` media file you can just convert it and assign it to `file.content` and then you can upload it.

Now, if you look at the [Telethon documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.downloads.DownloadMethods.download_media), you will see that `download_media()` takes a `file` argument which you can set to `bytes`:

> file (str | file, optional):
>
> The output file path, directory, or stream-like object. If the path exists and is a file, it will be overwritten. If file is the type bytes, it will be downloaded in-memory as a bytestring (e.g. file=bytes).

So you should be able to call `m.download_media(file=bytes)` to get a bytes object. Looking [even deeper](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/v1/telethon/client/downloads.py#L531) at the Telethon source code it appears that this does return a `BytesIO` object. With this in mind, you can try the following change in your loop:

```
for m in client.iter_messages(c):
        if m.photo:
            gfile.content = io.BytesIO(m.download_media(file=bytes))
            gfile.Upload()
```

Note that I only tested the PyDrive side since I currently don't have access to the Telegram API, but looking at the docs I believe this should work. Let me know what happens.

##### Sources:

- PyDrive [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/index.html) and [source](https://github.com/googlearchive/PyDrive/tree/42022f9a1c48f435438fce74ad4032ec9f34cfd1)
- Telethon [docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/index.html) and [source](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I tried your suggested code 

`if m.video:
    gfile = drive.CreateFile({'title': "video.mp4", 'parents': [{'id': 'path_to_drive'}]})
    gfile.content = m.download_media(file=bytes)
    gfile.Upload()`

Comment: However, I am getting the below error after successful authentication:

`gfile.Upload() AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'`

Can you please help me with it?

Comment: Although, 
`gfile.content = io.BytesIO(m.download_media(file=bytes))`
`gfile.Upload()`

This worked and now downloading media is directly uploaded over drive. Thank you so much!

Comment: Good to hear! I figured that `download_media` would already turn it into `BytesIO` but I guess I was wrong. I've corrected my answer for future reference.

Comment: Note that it is possible to pass a `io.BytesIO()` instance as the file where `download_media` should save the data, so there's no need to use `bytes`. Great answer nonetheless.